# lldb Xcode not responding | Fabric .pcm file duplication

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, lldb, google-fabric

I am using Fabric & Firestore in my project. While importing Firebase in any file inside project my lldb stops working.

Below is a snap of the error:

[image]

From the above, I figured that the problem is with the Fabric which is creating duplicate **.pcm** file inside Derived data's directory module-cache.

**LLDB Works:** If I remove all imports from the files followed by clean & run after deleting Derived data.

In my view, the solution might be restricting Fabric from creating duplicate .pcm files in the respective directory. So, how can we achieve this? Or, is there any other way to handle it?

Xcode Version: 10.1

Pods for Fabric & Firebase:

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.8.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.11.1'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project and removing `DerivedData` folder?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It didn't work out.

Comment: Try this. Open `Pod` target and go to `Build Phase`. Then start searching for the file and check whether it is duplicated or not. If so, remove one and re-run the project.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, what made it work was to import FirebaseCore, Fabric and Crashlytics separately instead of just the umbrella header Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. What I noticed was whole pods folder in "User Header Search Paths", so Fabric imported twice. I remove it and all begans working.

Answer (score 0):

We had this same issue after upgrading from an older Fabric integration to Firebase. We use Carthage, not Cocoapods.

It seems that removing the `import Fabric` and `import Crashlytics` statements, in favor of only using the umbrella `import Firebase`, solves the issue. The Firebase header includes both Fabric and Crashlytics.

**Edit:** Turns out this didn't solve our issue. It seems to have helped but sometimes the error still pops up.